# Exchange 2016 migration - MAPI/CDO tracing

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2016, mapi

[Microsoft has stated that Exchange MAPI over CDO will no longer be supported by Exchange 2016.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2015/06/18/mapi-cdo-will-not-be-supported-for-exchange-2016/)  We are working on migrating our 2010 environment to either 2013 or 2016, and this is our primary concern.  We have numerous legacy applications that have simply been left to run, and many we have no idea how they connect to Exchange.

Is there a way that I can identify them in logs, or an application, or anything on the Exchange side?  I can't just go to all the applications to identify them (we have over 17k documented applications in our environment)...

Comment: I would answer the second part of the question - Yes, you can turn on logging for every Exchange protocol if desired.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2015/04/20/a-better-way-to-collect-logs-from-your-exchange-servers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As MAPI use the RPC's port, it would be easier to validate in your inventory tool the remote computers to check if [Collaboration Data Objects, version 1.2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3671) is installed or not. That is a pre-req to have your CDO working. I assume you have Office 2007 or later deployed. As any program that use CDO would need it.

*Beginning in Exchange Server 2007 and Outlook 2007, CDO 1.2.1 will no longer be provided as a part of the install of the product. As a result, there is functionality missing that many applications depend upon. CDO 1.2.1 is a package providing access to Outlook-compatible objects through a COM-based API.*

Check that chart for CDO version bundle with what; https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/171440